# LINQ: Trouble Using Find or Where on database list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have some code in MVC POST method. I am trying simply to compare the username returned in the ViewModel to the EF collection returned from the database. Basically I want a Boolean result. I tried using Find but it doesn't let me specify a Lambda. I tried using Where but it returns a list and won't let me use FirstOrDefault. Can I please get some help?

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
        {
            try
            {
                using (PrefCenterEntities db = new PrefCenterEntities())
                {
                    var userName = loginModel.UserName;
                    var passWord = loginModel.Password;

                    User pcUser = new User
                    {
                        UserName = userName,
                        Password = passWord
                    };

                    // Find if already exists
                    if (db.Users.Where(y => System.String.Compare(y.UserName, loginModel.UserName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).FirstOrDefault())



                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried using Where but it returns a list and won't let me use
>   FirstOrDefault.

You need [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) like:

```
if (db.Users.Any(y => System.String.Compare(y.UserName, loginModel.UserName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
```

If you are going to use `FirstOrDefault` then compare it against `null` like:

```
if (db.Users.Where(y => System.String.Compare(y.UserName, loginModel.UserName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).FirstOrDefault() != null)
```

Or

```
if (db.Users.FirstOrDefault(y => System.String.Compare(y.UserName, loginModel.UserName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) != null)
```

It appears that you are trying to do case insensitive comparison, you have two options for that. Use `string.Equals` which takes a parameter to specify insensitive case comparison like:

```
if (db.Users.Any(y => System.String.Equals(y.UserName, loginModel.UserName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
```

or if there is an issue converting `String.Equals` to under lying data source language then convert your both values to upper case then compare like:

```
if (db.Users.Any(y => y.UserName != null && loginModel.UserName != null &&
                     y.UserName.ToUpper() == loginModel.UserName.ToUpper()))
{
   //record exits. 
}
```